# Are squawk codes used with ADS-B?

Tags: air-traffic-control, ads-b

When using ADS-B are squawk codes still necessary or does the unit provide a discrete code (like a tail number or something) that is recognized by ATC?

Comment: Are you asking if a transponder is still required? The answer to that question is absolutely yes. Having ADS-B out doesn't remove the requirements for certain airspaces where you need a transponder. Sounds redundant but makes sense when you think of all the existing TCAS systems that rely on it.

Comment: @RonBeyer I may be wrong about this but I thought the goal in the US was for ADS-B to *replace* mode c/s in the near future. But the question is more about if the *system* uses squawk codes.

Comment: ADS-B uses a unique code assigned to the airframe for it's life.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @Simon Does the atc system use that code to recognize you?

Comment: ADS-B does not use squawk codes, and squawk codes are not going away anytime soon, see [FAA ADS-B FAQ, #21 - *Will Mode-C Transponders be required indefinitely?*](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/programs/adsb/faq/#21) Its possible in the future that ADS-B will remove the transponder requirement, but not in the near future. So the *system* will continue to use transponder codes as far as I'm aware. The FAQ page I linked has some good info.

Comment: @RonBeyer Reading that very page is what prompted my question. I had misread the sentence that said "not in the near future, though." I was just kinda wondering if you're not in contact with ATC and squawking VFR if ATC can see info like who you are or what type of craft you are

Comment: Yeah, ATC should be able to see at least your N-Number and aircraft type if you are squawking VFR, as per Voretaq's answer below. I'm not sure if you should count on it though until NexGen is fully implemented and all radar stations are upgraded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, squawk codes are still used and required with ADS-B.
It's possible that in the future this may change, but because of the bifurcated implementation the FAA has chosen for ADS-B I don't think it's likely.

ADS-B operates by giving *additional* information beyond the Mode A (squawk) code - this is either encoded on the 1090MHz transponder frequency (Mode S "Extended Squitter" - what most of the world uses) or sent on a separate frequency (the 987MHz "Universal Access Transceiver" frequency, which is a US/FAA only thing mainly intended for light GA aircraft).

The Mode S and Extended Squitter data includes things like the aircraft's unique Mode S address (a 24-bit number assigned to the aircraft by its national registry, in the US this is linked to the N number), and may also provide the tail number or flight number. The ATC radar system will accept and display this information for the controller.
At the moment the Mode S/ES data is not used as a substitute for the Mode A transponder code, but because Mode S data is coming through the ATC secondary radar system it's all immediately available with the secondary radar return the same way a Mode A squawk code is, and it's possible that the FAA may use the Mode S ID in place of the Mode A squawk code for these aircraft in the future.

The 987MHz UAT transmissions also include the Mode S address (because it's a useful unique identifier for a given aircraft) and flight ID/tail number can be sent as well. Information from UAT transmitters is received through separate ground stations and recombined with the radar return in the ATC radar back-end.
There's some magic to that recombining which is out of my depth, but my limited understanding is that since the UAT data isn't directly correlated with a radar return squawk codes are part of how the two are matched up (the radar computer knows your N number by your discrete squawk code, the UAT ground station knows it from your Mode S ID - if they match and the position data is within reason the ADS-B information can be associated with your radar data block).

Comment: The ADS-B data format actually includes a provision for broadcasting the Mode A code, so no fanciful correlation with SSR data is necessary to display it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Do you have a reference for that? I thought there was something for it (it makes sense!) but I couldn't find anything in a quick search, and all the stuff I've been looking at is 1090ES so I'm not too familiar with the details of ADS-B Out on UAT hardware.

Comment: What I looked at was DO-260B, which is 1090ES, but I (perhaps wrongly) assumed that it's the same message formats that are being tunneled over the UAT channel. (For 1090ES, the draft of DO-260B that I was able to read without paying through the nose adds the Mode A code to the DF=17, Type=28, Subtype=1 message).

Comment: And now I discover that UAT actually uses a completely different message format, so I actually don't know what I thought I knew. :-(